# Is possible to figure out how many items a customer has ordered over time?

Tags: square-connect

I looked through the API and didn't see answer. I'd like to get how many of a particular item each customer ordered. Is that possible through the Square API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you associate transactions with customers, you can go through all your transactions and see how many each customer has purchased.